# c#: how to make additional delay

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

Here's My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
 async Task Do()
 {
  var i = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtLine(0);

  await Task.Delay(1000);
  textview.Buffer.Insert(ref i, "Hello, world!\n");
 }

 async void Main()
 {
  await Do();
  await Do();
 }

 public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
 {
  Build();
  Main();
 }

 protected void OnPauseButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
 }
}
```

What I intended is:

If I press button before first "Hello, world!" appears, Two "Hello, world" would appear with an interval of a second after 5 seconds passed.

But, What Really Happend:

I pressed button before first "Hello, world!" appears, and 5 seconds has passed, Two "Hello, world" appeared simultaniously.

What's the solution for this?

Comment: try disabling the button and then enabling after task has completed. Alternatively use a boolean field to check whether task is in progress and discard any new calls.

Comment: is the Thread.Sleep blocking your main thread for 5 seconds, then when that blocking has completed to two tasks have already returned and so you are shown both "Hello world"s?

Comment: @the_doc Yes, surely.

Comment: don't do `async void` in C#, it's a trap!